# What name should be given to uploaded files in android

Tags: android, file, file-upload

As I upload the images to server from app, I save a copy of that in the sent_images folder of my app.(The images are kept saved whether these are successfully uploaded Or not, for Retry purpose.)
The problem is that I use the System.currentTimeMillis() +".jpg" as the file name. But the file name may be repeated sometime in extreme case when the user backdates his device time. And unfortunately, the time the image upload is tried again, the System.currentTimeMillis() gives the same timestamp as given in previous file upload attempt.
Help!

Comment: You can add file size to the name of file...

Comment: I usually put namefile_timestamp.jpg but this timestamp is added by the server, not by the mobile

Comment: @zozelfelfo "timestamp is added by the server?". But the files are being saved on device.

Answer (score 1):

You can compute the file hash:

```
MessageDigest md = MessageDigest.getInstance("MD5");
try (InputStream is = Files.newInputStream(Paths.get("file.txt"))) {
  DigestInputStream dis = new DigestInputStream(is, md);
  /* Read stream to EOF as normal... */
}
byte[] digest = md.digest();
```

Comment: If I save the same file twice. Would the file hash be different then?

Comment: no, but you can concatenate with the hash. And even if the user changes the phone's date/time, it would be less probable to can upload the same file at the exact time(exact milliseconds).